# while Converting Object[] to String[] iam getting java.lang.ArrayStoreException for the following code

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv

```
public void createCSV(Map<String, Object> map) {
   String  reportPath =  "C:/Users/nandini/Desktop/file.csv";

    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(reportPath);
        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(fileWriter,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
                CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);


        String[] header = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
        


        Object[] data = map.values().toArray(new Object[map.size()]);
        String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length, String[].class);

        // adding data to csv
        csvWriter.writeNext(header);
        csvWriter.writeNext(stringArray);            
        csvWriter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);

    }
}
```

Comment: Not every value object was a `String`. You can't assume otherwise. You have to test, or use `String.valueOf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens due to the following line:

```
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length, String[].class);
```

The [method Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(U%5B%5D,int,java.lang.Class)) states that the method throws an `ArrayStoreException` *if an element copied from original is not of a runtime type that can be stored in an array of class newType*.

So if the `Object[]` array contains an element that is not a `String`, this exception will be thrown. Instead of casting the element to a `String`, you can get its string representation using the `toString()` method:

```
String[] stringArray = Arrays.stream(data)
                             .map(Object::toString)
                             .toArray(size -> new String[size]);
```

**EDIT:**

Without streams...

```
String[] stringArray = new String[data.length];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    stringArray[i] = data[i].toString();
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to write in java1.7

Comment: @nandini Just do a simple loop over the `Object[]` array and assign each object's `toString()` to the `String[]` array. I recommend you try to write it on your own, it be much better :)